# fast way to get mean,sum,ect.. between two dates depending on an other Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently trying to find a fast way to derive a column. To be more precise I have two dataframes: the first one with two columns ('Open_date','Close_date'), the second one is a time series with in index the dates, and in columns 'interest rate'. 
I would like to get fastly for instance the mean of the interest rate between this two dates for all the row in my first dataframe.

Because one image is often better than 1000 words, here is the slow way of doing it :

```
df1 =pd.DataFrame({'Open_date' : np.array(pd.date_range('20130101',periods = 6 )),
              'Close_date' : np.array(pd.date_range('20130104',periods = 6 ))
                    })
df1=df1[ [ 'Open_date','Close_date']]


df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20,1), index=pd.date_range('20130101',periods = 20), columns= ['interest_rate'])

list=[]
for i in range(df1.shape[0]):
     list.append(df2.loc[df1['Open_date'][i]:df1['Close_date'][i],:]['interest_rate'].mean())

df1['mean_interest_rate'] = list
```

Is there a way to do it without a loop ? by a vectorial way ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: fix my answer ? I don't understand .. Do you mean that i need to add examples of dataframes in my question ?

Comment: *question... my bad. And yes! I do.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible sample data :)

Comment: I am doing it, just a moment please !

Comment: Is more clear now ?

Comment: @JeanGuillaume update , should be fast that for loop ~ , let us wait for other genius solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
df=df1.copy()#keep the original df1
df1['list']=df1.apply(lambda x : pd.date_range(start =x['Open_date'],end=x['Close_date'],freq='D').tolist(),axis=1)
df1=df1['list'].apply(pd.Series).stack().to_frame().rename(columns={0:'Date'})
df1['value']=df1.Date.map(df2.interest_rate)
df1.groupby(level=0).mean()


Out[377]: 
      value
0  0.617968
1  0.832764
2  0.606520
3  0.883619
4 -0.337306
5 -0.506201


pd.concat([df,df1.groupby(level=0).mean()],axis=1)

Out[389]: 
   Open_date Close_date     value
0 2013-01-01 2013-01-04 -0.206509
1 2013-01-02 2013-01-05  0.058621
2 2013-01-03 2013-01-06 -0.041077
3 2013-01-04 2013-01-07 -0.254862
4 2013-01-05 2013-01-08 -0.638243
5 2013-01-06 2013-01-09 -0.891294
```

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, I am going to assume you can join these data frames based on some keys or that their indices are the same.

If the first is the case:

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2,on="someCommonColumn",how="inner")
```

If the second is the case:

```
df = df2
df["endDate"] = df1["endDate"]
df["startDate"] = df1["startDate"]
```

To find the mean of a column, for instance  "interestRate", between two dates, utilise conditional statements, such that:

```
import numpy 
meanInterestRate = numpy.mean(df.loc[(df["startDate"] > someDate)&(df["endDate"] < someOtherDate),"interestRate"])
```

Comment: But when you will join or merge, you will lost information that you need to derive the mean between two dates, to be more precise, we lost interest rates bewteen Open_date and Close_date, is not it ?

Comment: No because the aim would be to directly attribute an interest rate to a date range. The mean would be based on the subset of the joined dataframe. Either consistent indicies or one or more columns to join are required for this though, as specified at the start of the answer.

Comment: Yes but i have not consistent indices or keys..Thank you for your help !

Comment: Then this approach will not work sorry. I am interested to see how you will achieve this without common keys.

Comment: You can look the Wen's answer  above !